# Equivalent of AUC (area under the ROC curve) for two variables

Tags: classification, auc

I was wondering if there is a way to compute AUC using two variables instead of one as predictors.

I got two populations after a follow-up, divided in Cases and Controls according to whether they had developed or not a pathology during the follow-up. There are also two independent variables in the data and now I would like to find a way to combine these two to see if any combination of them could enhance predictability.

I've already tried combining many variables (a total of 39, including the two I am asking this question about) with principle component analysis (PCA), but it did not improve the predictability, so  I want to try something else. I know that some use C-index, but I know nothing about it.

**Clarification.** Suppose that the two variables I have are: a measure of the length of an heartbeat, also called RR, and a measure of the quantity of the blood ejected at every heartbeat, also called LVEF. I know that these two variables yield  AUCs of 0.61 and 0.65, respectively, when used separately. Is there a way I could combine these two AUCs for RR and LVEF?

Comment: There are votes to close this question as unclear. However, I think it is pretty clear, and I edited it to improve readability.

Comment: One sentence that *is* unclear is the one about PCA. I still don't understand it, even after your edit.

Comment: I'll try to explain. I know that a way to combine different independent parameters on a data set is PCA, thus i've tried PCA for some indipendent parameters (a total of 39) i have on the data set, which include the two parameters for which i asked the question. However, i found no improvement of predicitivity using PCA, thus i'm searching some other methods to combine two or more parameters. I hope to have clarified the statement.

Comment: When you say "parameters" I think you mean variables, but even if that's right what do you mean by combining variables? There are any number of ways of doing it; for all we know $\ln x_1/x_2$ or $(x_1 - x_2) / (x_1 + x_2)$ could be what you want. Without specifics how could I combine variables is no less general than what calculations could I do? (Mentioning that you are interested in something pathological doesn't tie this down statistically.)

Comment: No,no, i meant parameters. Let assume that these two populations are Cases if they experience infarction or Controls otherwise. There are few cardiac parameter that one could compute such as QT-interval, RR, QRS amplitude and so on. These are some of the input parameters of PCA. Among these, i have to combine two of them to test enhanced predictivity. What represent the formula you cited?
i apologize if my answers are not clear, i'm not a native english speaker and not a statistican at all, i do some biomedical research with basic statistical knowledge.

Comment: Statistically, those are variables, not parameters. A parameter in statistics is a constant you are estimating. I am guessing that something like QT-interval varies between people or for a person over time, etc. That would make QT-interval a variable, not a parameter. My larger comment remains: any kind of combination could make sense, so your question is, so far as I can see, completely open.

Comment: Yeah, all these are time and person dependant, thus, as you say, they are variables. The point of the question remains: how could i combine them? Which information could i provide to help in chosing a combining technique?

Comment: Like @Nick, I'm struggling to understand what you need.  Would it perhaps be [symbolic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22symbolic%20regression%22)?

Comment: I dont know how could i explain me better than i've done but i'll try. Suppose that the two variables i have are: a misure of the length of an heartbeat, also called RR, and a measure of the quantity of the blood ejected at every heartbeat, also called LVEF. I know that these two variables yeld an AUC of 0.61 and 0.65, respectively, when used singularly. Of course, to find those AUC values, i used a threshold: in those cases, since median(Cases)>median(Ctrl), i chosed the 75th percentile on the Controls distribution as threshold of pathology. Now, is there a way i could combine RR and LVEF?

Comment: @NickCox: I am surprised that many people find this question unclear. AUC is a number that is sometimes used to measure separability of two classes with respect to a single variable of interest (one can e.g. use Cohen's $d$ instead). OP is asking how to generalize AUC, or what other measures of separability can be used, when there are two variables of interest. E.g. variables can be height and weight, and classes can be patients and controls. The answer should probably mention MANOVA, LDA, classification accuracies, etc.

Comment: @amoeba Glad you got your way towards an interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the AUC for the combination of two variables, you can include both as predictors in a logistic regression model and compute the AUC using the predictions from the model. See some sample code:

```
library(pROC)
data(infert)
auc(case ~ age, data=infert)   #Compute AUC for predicting case with the variable age
mod1<-glm(case ~ age + parity, data=infert, family="binomial")  #Logistic regression model
auc(case ~ predict(mod1), data=infert)  #Compute AUC for predicting case with your model
```

Comment: what's the code for?

Comment: It's an example of computing the AUC for a logistic regression model including two variables (age and parity) as predictors. You are using both variables to predict a third one (case), as you stated in your question.

Comment: hmmm, i'm not sure i've understood what you've done, but i'll try something according, maybe trying will help me. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: +1. It is a reasonable approach, @Ciochi. Perhaps I can add that the AUC is a measure that (by definition) only makes sense if you have one variable. So if you have several variables and still want to use AUC, then the question is how to combine these several variables into one variable. Of course you want to combine them such that the difference between groups becomes as high as possible. There are various ways to find such "optimal" combinations, and logistic regression is one good way. Another way is linear discriminant analysis.

Comment: First i'll try the linear regression model. But i need to be sure that i work fine. Take this function in matlab:
http://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html
which is defined like this:

b = glmfit(X,y,distr) [..] X is an n-by-p matrix of p predictors at each of n observations[..] y is an n-by-1 vector of observed responses. 

In my case, given N1 as the dimension of Controls and N2 the dimension of Cases, X may be a (N1+N2)x 2, with the two columns being the two variables, and y a vector of 0 or 1 according to Nth observation being a Control or a subject.

Comment: I've worked a little bit with the data. One issue that i found is that Cases and Controls have different size. Thus, i cannot build a n-by-p vector of observation that is consistant. Moreover, i am not that sure what to do with the resulting coefficients of the model, even if i succeed in making a linear regression.

Comment: For anyone interested, i managed to export the data to R and analyze them using the code aghila provided. Indeed, combining various parameters, i succeeded in enhancing AUC. Maybe i'll ask for some help in R programming to avoid making sequential comparison manually using some looping techinques. Thanks to all have contributed.

Comment: Could you explain the theoretical foundation for this approach?